# How can I nest an object in an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a function that generates the following object:

```
const currentObject = {
  labels: {
    x1: "y1",
    x2: "y2",
    x3: "y3",
  }
}
```

To handle it in my api it should have a format like this:

```
const targetObject = { 
    labels: {
        templatename:{
            x1: "y1",
            x2: "y2",
            x3: "y3",
        }
    }
}

const templatename = this.props.templatename;
```

How can I nest an object in an object with the template name in the const?

I don't want to paste a bunch of code, the two objects are just an example and the first one can be generated by the following function:

```
state = {
        "labels": {

        }
    }

onChange = (e, key) => {
    this.setState({
        labels: {
            ...this.state.labels,
            [key]: e.target.value
        }
    });
```

Comment: _I got a function that generates the following json object._ Where is the function?

Comment: How the object is generated seems totally irrelevant. I'd rollback the edit.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's just JavaScript literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean using a dynamic key? You can try:

```
const targetObject = {
  labels: {
    [this.props.templatename]: { ...currentObject.labels }
  }
};
```

---

```
const targetObject = {
  labels: {
    [this.props.templatename]: {
      x1: 'y1',
      x2: 'y2',
      x3: 'y3'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: @J.Adam if an answer solves the problem for you, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the ✓ rather than posting this (you might need to wait a few minutes). Take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

```
const updatedObj = {
  labels: {
   templatename: {
     ...currentObject.labels
   }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this function, wich is testable and also, can handle any prop and template name.

```js
const currentObject = {
    "labels": {
        "x1": "y1",
        "x2": "y2",
        "x3": "y3",
    }
}

function nestObjectByProperty(currentObj, propName, templateName){
  return {
    [propName]: {
      [templateName]: currentObj[propName]
    }
  }
}
const targetObj = nestObjectByProperty(currentObject, 'labels', 'templatename')

console.log(targetObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object and use `Object.assign`

```js
const currentObject = {
  "labels": {
    "x1": "y1",
    "x2": "y2",
    "x3": "y3",
  }
}

let newObj = Object.assign({}, {
  currentObject: {
    labels: {
      templatename: currentObject.labels
    }
  }
});

console.log(newObj)
```